# AIC in R fGarch Package

Tags: r, aic, garch

I am using the R package `fGARCH` to analyze stock market volatility. In order to test the goodness of fit I compare the AIC values of different model specifications. One thing I noticed is that the AIC that I calculate manually via the formula $\text{AIC} = 2k - 2\ln(L)$ where $L$ is the Likelihood value, does not equal the AIC output by the Fit object.

Does the package `fGARCH` use a different equation to calculate the AIC?

Comment: Are the likelihood values the same in both cases that you are comparing? It often happens that likelihoods ignore constants. That still allows for comparing likelihood values or AIC values across models as long as the constant that is ignored is the same in all cases.

Answer (score 2):

Most GARCH packages use a scaled version, given by $AIC/n$, where $n$ is your sample size.

Thus, multiplying the $AIC$ value from the `fGARCH` object with the sample size, you should get the desired result.